# NodeJS - TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am getting the following error from my code: If you could help me that would be amazing! I am using discord.js!

---

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined at
> files.forEach.file (/root/eternity-bot/eternity-bot/index.js:21:33) at
> Array.forEach () at fs.readdir
> (/root/eternity-bot/eternity-bot/index.js:18:9) at
> FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)

---

```
fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  files.forEach(file => {
    if (!file.endsWith(".js")) return;
    let props = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    console.log(`Loading Command: ${props.help.name}.`);
    bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
    props.conf.aliases.forEach(alias => {
      bot.aliases.set(alias, props.help.name);
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: Please paste the contents of the js file in the commands folder.

Comment: What is props retuning? it does not have help tag .... let props = require(`./commands/${file}`);
console.log(`Loading Command: ${props.help.name}.`);

Comment: Either you are not importing the props file, or the help property does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TypeError:** A [TypeError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError) is thrown when an operand or argument passed to a function is incompatible with the type expected by that operator or function.

The possible cause is your `props` is not loaded correctly and doesn't include any property `help`, thus accessing property `name` of unknown property `help` throws TypeError. Similar to following:

```
let obj = {
    o1: {
        a: 'abc'
    }
};

obj.o1     // gives {a: 'abc'}, as o1 is property obj which is an object.
obj.o1.a   // gives 'abc', as a is property of o1, which is property of obj.
obj.o2     // undefined, as there's no o2 property in obj.
obj.o2.a   // TypeError as there's no o2 property of obj and thus accessing property a of undefined gives error.
```

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that the code is working perfectly fine, but there seems to be some problem with the exports of your javascript files in the commands folder. Most probably, the help property is not defined in your files.